# Replacing char with single quote using tr in shell scripting

Tags: shell, unix, tr

I want to replace new line char(\n) with `','` (along with starting and closing single quotes) in shell script by using `tr` command. But `tr` command is not replacing char correctly

Here is the command i used:

```
< 1.txt tr "\n" "','"
```

Output for this command :

```
erer'erer.'erer'erer'
```

File 1.txt is like :

```
erer
erer.
erer
erer
```

Please suggest me how this can be done using the same command.

Question Edited

Comment: `tr "\n" "'"` should work.

Comment: Or try: `tr "\r\n" "'"`

Comment: @anubhava - Sorry i edited the question. My question was sightly different. Sorry my mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tr is not the right tool for this since tr does char by char translation instead of char to a string replacement. use awk:

```
awk '{printf("'"'"'%s'"'"',", $0)} END{print ""}' 1.txt
```

To avoid all weird double quote/single quote stuff use:

```
awk '{printf("\x27%s\x27,", $0)} END{print ""}' 1.txt
```

To avoid printing comma after last line:

```
awk '{a[cnt++]=$0} END{ for (i=0; i<length(a)-1; i++) printf("\x27%s\x27,", a[i]); 
      print a[i]}' 1.txt
```

Comment: @anubhava- Thanks!!... Can you please explain above awk command?

Comment: Ya sure. It is actually a very simple awk command but looks clunky because of singl and double quotes. It is basically wrapping each line `$0` in single quotes and appending comma after it. Finally it prints a new line.

Comment: @MayankJain: I provided another awk command to simplify previous one.

Comment: @MayankJain: No it won't fail with spaces in the line since I use `$0` to capture/print it. Try it out.

Comment: What if my file 1.txt is like 
1234  RUN434345(Newlinechar here)
2323  DFD343434(Newlinechar here)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32408/discussion-between-mayank-jain-and-anubhava)

Answer (score 2):

`tr` is only to transliterate characters. You could do:

```
$ seq 10 | sed "s/.*/'&'/" | paste -sd, -
'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'
```

Or if you don't want the first and last `'`:

```
$ seq 10 | sed '$!G;$!G' | paste -sd "','" -
1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10
```